# Excel is getting corrupted while opening the file created with POI API

Tags: java, apache-poi

```
public static void createworkbook() throws IOException, InvalidFormatException{

    File file = new File("C:\\Workspace\\Selenium_2.53\\src\\InputFiles\\webuyPurchase.xlsx");
    file.createNewFile();
    fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    workbook.write(fileOut);
    XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("Products");
    String sheetname =  workbook.getSheetAt(0).getSheetName();
    System.out.println(sheetname);
    fileOut.close();
    // workbook.createSheet("Products");
    System.out.println("workbook is created");
}
```

While executing the above code , File is created successfully. But File is found corrupted during opening it.

Comment: Mhh .. what could be the reason ... ? First you write an empty workbook, then you modify it ... maybe one should do it the other way round ...

Comment: Hi kiwiwings , I have no clue why the file is getting corrupted , Last time when i created the file , it had zero sheets , that's why it was giving error , now this time i have created the sheet init and accessed it's name to , That means sheet is present , Still giving error .

Comment: ok ... it seems you don't understand, although you've written the answer "it had zero sheets" yourself. Please move the line `workbook.write(fileOut);` 3 lines further down ....

Comment: Thanks a ton kiwiwings , It works now.

Comment: @kiwiwings you should put that as an answer, considering it is one (even if the question is a bit silly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you've corrected the order of your statements, it should look like this ...
so it's not necessary to create the file via `file.createNewFile()` beforehand

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class CreateWorkbook {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("Products");
        spreadsheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("this is a test");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("bla.xlsx");
        workbook.write(fos);
        fos.close();
        workbook.close();
    }
}
```